# Problem deserialising a message from a topic in kafka using spring

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, avro

The consumer is throwing these errors when I try to read from the queue, I think it is because I am not configuring the deserializer properly, as I understand it should be the same in the consumer and the producer, so I created the same avro for both, for a while it was working but it has stopped working and I do not know very well why.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
Exception in thread "Promotions_Handler-a2f86d00-554e-43c5-b984-faafb7524faf-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:82)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:185)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:895)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:1008)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:812)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:625)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:564)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:523)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 24, 77, 49, 50, 50, 57, 57, 115, 100, 97, 115, 102, 53]] from topic [Queue_Garment]
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x1174d31 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.reportInvalid(UTF32Reader.java:195)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.read(UTF32Reader.java:158)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._loadMore(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:255)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2389)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:677)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._initForReading(ObjectReader.java:355)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2023)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1528)
at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:534)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeKey(SourceNode.java:54)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:65)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:185)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:895)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:1008)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:812)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:625)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:564)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:523)
```

The consumer body:

```
@StreamListener
public KStream<GarmentKey, GarmentEvent> newGarment(@Input(BinderProcessor.Queue_Garment)KStream<GarmentKey,GarmentEvent> garment){
    updateDatabase(garment);
    uploadGarmentToQueue(garment);
    return garment.peek(((GarmentKey,GarmentEvent) -> System.out.println("promotion body ="+GarmentKey.toString())));
}
```

The producer body :

```
public void postGarment(PostGarmentDto postGarmentDto) {
        if(goodReference(postGarmentDto.getReference())) {
            GarmentKey garmentKey = new GarmentKey();
            garmentKey.setReference(postGarmentDto.getReference());
            GarmentEvent garmentEvent = new GarmentEvent();
            garmentEvent.setCategory(postGarmentDto.getCategory());
            garmentEvent.setPrice(postGarmentDto.getPrice());
            kafkaTemplate.send("Queue_Garment", garmentKey, garmentEvent);
        }
    }
```

Consumer.yml

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: default
  application:
    name: Promotions_Handler
  kafka:
    consumer:
      key-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    properties:
        streams:
          binder:
            auto-create-topics: true
            configuration:
              state.dir: /tmp
              commit.interval.ms: 100
              topology.optimization: all
              session.timeout.ms: 10000
              schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
              auto.register.schemas: true
              default.key.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
              default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.Queue_Promotions_Applied:
  destination: Queue_Promotions_Applied
  producer:
    useNativeEncoding: true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.Queue_Garment:
  destination: Queue_Garment
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.Queue_Promotions:
  destination: Queue_Promotions
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: true
```

Producer.yml

```
  spring:
  application:
    name: Garment_receiver
  kafka:
    properties:
      bootstrap.servers: localhost:9092
      schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
    producer:
      key-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your consumer properties need to be ***de***-serializers

As indicated in the stacktrace, it's set to JsonDeserializer, apparently, not Avro

Also, I don't think `spring.kafka.properties` is where you configure `streams.binder` since that's for Spring-kafka (which also has Kafka Streams support), not Spring Cloud Stream...

You want `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration` - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_binder_properties

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the problem was in the application.yml, at the time of putting the deserialicer, I will take into account what you say about the properites, since it is my first project with kafka and I am not very in the mood yet.

Thank you very much!